# storing medications in checked baggage

Tags: luggage

I have medication that should not be stored in temperatures below 59 degrees or above 86 degrees (F) - can these be put in my checked luggage? This is Lodocaine/prilocaine

Comment: Where are you flying from/to/through? In Miami or Phoenix, it is hotter than that. In Anchorage or Novosibirsk, it's colder than that. Luggage is not air-conditioned, but sits around on the tarmac or kn the airport for a while usually.

Comment: Consider that while luggage usually doesn't get lost, sometimes it does. Many of us carry in hand luggage stuff that's really important and shouldn't be lost...like medicines or a laptop computer.

Answer (score 1):

No

Checked luggage spends a fair bit of time outdoors, on the tarmac, and in storage facilities that are not climate controlled. So temperatures can vary quite a bit depending on weather and environment.

Also temperature in the baggage hold is on average significantly colder than in the passenger cabin. Temperature varies quite a bit but the average is around 45 deg Fahrenheit. https://bestcheckedluggage.com/cold-luggage-plane/

No one knows for sure, but it's very likely that the drugs will see temperature outside the recommended range if you check them